# Apply a function on each nested row separately

Tags: r

I am nesting data and want to take weights on the dataset. However, I want to use an inner nest as a weight and have this different in value.

For example, by using the iris data:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest(.) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% transmute(
  Sepal = apply(across(starts_with('Sepal')), 1, function(x)
    weighted.mean(x, c(0.20, 0.30))),
  Petal = apply(across(starts_with('Petal')), 1, function(x)
    weighted.mean(x, c(0.25, 0.35)))
)))
```

I can get specific weights over columns, however I want to all take weights for the nested groups i.e.

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    data             
  <fct>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 2]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 2]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 2]>
```

an extra weight for each species such that `c(0.15, 0.20, 0.25)` when performing the calculation. The best I can try is adding an extra column with the value `1` however I do not know how to make each weighted dependent on the nested group.

Something like:

```
setosa*Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width ~ 0.15*0.20*0.30
versicolor*Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width ~ 0.20*0.20*0.30
...
```

Comment: Avoid using `apply`. use `rowwise` etc

Comment: have a nested column of weights with respect to species

Comment: @onyambu whats the difference? They can both produce the same result and speed is not much important for my case. Additionally, I had thought your attempt before but all weights must sum to 1, therefore how would you take this into consideration? Your approach only appends the additional weight value to the list of weights.

Comment: its not a matter of speed. You are working with dataframes and `apply` is not recommended when working on dataframes. If you were working on matrices then thats fine. Otherwise consider having your data in a tidy format to use groupby/or columnwise functions

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for the tip, I will try keeping that in mind when working with dataframes.